# How to set header in xml android?

Tags: xml, android-layout, graphics, android

i have a header in page of my app , in this header have 2 icon and 1 logo .
my problem is i can't full header in top of page , i want top of the page is complete header

please say me to how do it ?

tanks for help

i made like this :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/PMdh7.jpg

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="#232043" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="#1b0534"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/helpi"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/helpi"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/abouti"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:src="@drawable/abouti"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logoi"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/lhead"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="#3c2b86"
        android:drawableLeft="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="15dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText,ExtraText,TextFields" >

"

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:divider="#100826"
        android:dividerHeight="0.5dp"
        android:listSelector="#1b0534"
        android:scrollbars="none" >

    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Are you talking about ActionBar title?

Comment: yes , what do i say ?

Answer (score 0):

You may try something like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="#232043"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/headerlayout"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:weightSum="8"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            //Your Header Images and Icons Here
            //You may use weights to fill them the screen

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/header"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:background="#1b0534"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/helpi"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/helpi"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/abouti"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/abouti"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/logoi"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/lhead"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />
        </LinearLayout>


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
            android:background="#3c2b86"
            android:drawableLeft="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
            android:ems="10"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="15dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            tools:ignore="HardcodedText,ExtraText,TextFields" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

        <ListView
            android:id="@android:id/list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:divider="#100826"
            android:dividerHeight="0.5dp"
            android:listSelector="#1b0534"
            android:scrollbars="none" >
        </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Try adding weights to your image views. They might help in filling the complete screen. Do tell if you don't know how to use weights in linear layout

Comment: I have edited the post. Try understanding the use of weights. Its not exactly what you want but might help you :/